# TFRecords: Write list of tensors to single Example

Tags: tensorflow

I'm extracting features from images using a convolutional neural network. The network in question has three outputs (three output tensors), which differ in size. I want to store the extracted features in TFRecords, one Example for each image:

```
Example:
    image_id: 1
    features/fc8: [output1.1, output1.2, output1.3]
Example:
    image_id: 2
    features/fc8: [output2.1, output2.2, output2.3]
....
```

How can I achieve this structure using TFRecords?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Elegant way is to use tf.SequenceExample.

1. ## Convert the data using tf.SequenceExample() format

   ```
   def make_example(features, image_id):

     ex = tf.train.SequenceExample()   
     ex.context.feature['image_id'].int64_list.value.append(image_id)
     fl_features = ex.feature_lists.feature_list['features/fc8']

     for feature in features:
       fl_features.feature.add().bytes_list.value.append(frame.tostring())
     return ex
   ```
2. ## Writing to TFRecord

   ```
   def _convert_to_tfrecord(output_file, feature_batch, ids_batch):

     writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_file)

     for features, id in zip(feature_batch, ids_batch):
       ex = make_example(features, id)
       writer.write(ex.SerializeToString())
     writer.close()
   ```
3. ## Parsing example

   ```
   def parse_example_proto(example_serialized):

    context_features = {
       'image_id': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)}
    sequence_features = {
       'features/fc8': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.string)}

    context_parsed, sequence_parsed = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(
       serialized=example_serialized,
       context_features=context_features,
       sequence_features=sequence_features)
    return context_parsed['image_id'], sequence_features['features/fc8']
   ```

Note: The features here are saved in byte_list, you can also save it in float_list.
Another way, is to use tf.parse_single_example() by storing the examples as:

```
image_id: 1  
features/fc8_1: output1.1  
features/fc8_2: output1.2  
features/fc8_3: output1.3
```

Comment: I was using the second suggestion but I thought there has to be something more elegant, e.g. using SequenceExample. What I don't like is the fact that I would need to now how many outputs there are. For the first example: Would you then use tf.slice() for decoding?

Comment: Edited to use SequenceExample(); i was using it to save jpegs which is of different sizes for video work and this code was tested for this use case.

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for. How would you unpack the single tensors then? I'm using tf.unstack() but it needs the number of tensors, since the shape of sequence_features['features/fc8'] is (?,) and unfortunately it doesn't accept a tensor for the num parameter.

Comment: You generally pass the sequence_features to a queue for generating batches, but if you want to access individual elements you can use like, sequence_features['features/fc8'][0].

Comment: This only works when I know how many elements there are, same is true for tf.unstack() of course. But I guess there is no other way since the shape of that tensor is unknown: there could be any number of elements in that sequence.